# Deciding on cluster size setting in Carrot2

Tags: cluster-analysis, java, carrot2

I am using carrot2's STC (Suffix Tree Clustering) algorithm for clustering a bunch of documents. By default, the max number of clusters the algorithm forms is **16**. Is there a way to decide the number of clusters generated ?.

Below is the code for invoking STC clusters.

```
ProcessingResult byDomainClusters = controller.process(documents, null, STCClusteringAlgorithm.class);
List<Cluster> clustersByDomain = byDomainClusters.getClusters();
ConsoleFormatter.displayClusters(clustersByDomain);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get more clusters, try increasing the values of the [maxClusters](http://download.carrot2.org/stable/javadoc/org/carrot2/clustering/stc/STCClusteringAlgorithm.html#maxClusters) and [maxBaseClusters](http://download.carrot2.org/stable/javadoc/org/carrot2/clustering/stc/STCClusteringAlgorithm.html#maxBaseClusters) parameters. Here's how to [pass parameter values in Java code](http://download.carrot2.org/stable/javadoc/overview-summary.html#setting-attributes).

However, the low number of clusters may also be caused by the characteristics of your input data (too few documents?). To verify this, try clustering your data with the Lingo algorithm.